# Object has to many vectors

Tags: ios, scenekit, blender

I added a sphere to SceneKit which exported from with the UV unwrapped.

If I want to add an Image to that sphere it puts the parts of the image all over in the faces(?) of the sphere.

If I use a sphere from SceneKit it already fits on the sphere perfectly.

The left one is from scene kit and the other one is from blender. How do I make it look the same as the left one?
[image: The left one is from scene kit and the other one is from blender. How do I make it look the same as the left one?]

Basically what I want to do is import a sphere with a hole inside the sphere and add an 360 degree image in scenekit onto the sphere. Maybe someone can give me guide how to do this.

Comment: Did you use spherical mapping for the uv unwrapping? Does the texture show properly on the sphere inside blender?

Comment: I'm not sure I selected the sphere and pressed Unwrap and then exported it. I haven't assigned any material in blender because I want to add the image in scenekit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that there are two geometry elements, those 4 polygons on the front with the orange edges are a different element that the rest. That in turn causes the vertex and UV arrays to be misaligned.

I’m not familiar with Blender but I get the same thing in 3D studio max if I accidentally forgot to make sure all the faces have the same material assigned. On import XCode automatically divides a mesh into one element per assigned material. Can’t see it in your screenshot but I bet it has two materials as well.

If my assumption is correct the solution is to select all faces/polygons in Blender and reassign the material so all faces have the same material assigned.

Comment: Yes there is a hole in the middle which I cut out and there seem to be two materials. I just tried it with a model without the hole and now the image gets repeated on every little polygon.

Comment: That last part of your comment means every face is mapped to uv 0,0 to 1,1, so look into spherical mapping in Blender. If you haven’t assigned any material, somehow on export or import it got divided into two elements perhaps for other reasons. You could check the contents of the dae file in a text editor to see if it already had two materials assigned after exporting but before Xcode imports it. At least then you will know whether to blame Blender or Xcode for the double material and element.